# Apache fails to start on Vagrant

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, virtualbox, vagrant

In my Vagrant environment I have a guest Ubuntu Virtualbox with a LAMP with default settings.

I have my source code on the host machine in the same folder as my Vagrantfile. So on the guest Ubuntu I can access the files in the mounted `/vagrant` dir like this

```
/vagrant
  /mysite
    /index.php
  /Vagrantfile
```

Now in my Apache config I add a line

```
Alias /mysite /vagrant/mysite
```

After reloading config and restarting apache I can go to `localhost:8558/mysite/index.php` and it works.

The problem is that when I reload Virtualbox with `vagrant reload` it starts Apache service **before** mounting the `/vagrant` folder. So Apache can't find the aliased dir and fails to start. i have to start it manually then

My question is - is there a way to delay Apache start so that it starts after the mounting?

**Update:** As a workaround I added script to the crontab that starts apache 30 seconds after the boot as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up). But I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If upstart is installed (as in Ubuntu), Vagrant emits "vagrant-mounted" event. See https://serverfault.com/a/568033/179583 to get the idea. In your script you can (re)start the Apache server.

Btw, I have a feeling that newer Apache versions just warn, but still start even if the doc root doesn't exist. The same with nginx.

Comment: Another option for upstart enabled services is using [`respawn limit 10 5`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) in service upstart conf. This will try to start the service again up to 10 times with 5s intervals.

Answer (score 25):

while upstart probably is a valid option, I had several issues using it with vagrant. I had to run several tasks that needed to be run as a privileged user, which I did not manage to get working with upstart.

Starting from version 1.6.0 (May 6, 2014), vagrant provides the option to run a specific provisioner every time, so also after booting a halted VM with vagrant up.

In your `Vagrantfile`, add:

```
# a file, eg after-boot.sh
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "after-boot.sh", run: "always"
# or just inline
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "service apache2 restart", run: "always"
```

note the `run: "always"`, this will force vagrant to run the provisioner always, obviously it works just as well with any other provisioning system like chef or puppet.

Comment: after spending about 10 hours trying to get upstart working properly with my node project in vagrant, this ended up being my solution. I tried hooking onto the `vagrant-mounted` event but this ended up being the only solution.

Comment: yeah, I tried `vagrant-mounted` as well, but just couldn't get it working. I am now sailing pretty good with this solution, works quiet well.

Comment: added the "inline" version before the last "end" in the Vagrantfile. WORKED!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "systemctl restart httpd", run: "always"` worked for me on a Cent OS 7 base box.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add a little to Zauberfisch's answer ([Apache fails to start on Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599728/apache-fails-to-start-on-vagrant/23986680#23986680))

> What needed to happen was this command needed to be run as a superuser AKA 'Sudo' so this was the command that was needed:
>
> ```
> `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo service apache2 restart", run: "always"`
> ```

The reason why this didn't work for you without the `sudo` appears to be that Vagrant tries to run the command without `/usr/sbin` in `PATH`. For me, this worked just as well:

```
`config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart", run: "always"`
```